# How to factorize try/catch code?

Tags: c#

I have a C# code that is using an external library which can throw exceptions.
In three parts of my code, I want to process these exceptions the following way:

```
try {
   CallOtherLibrary();
}
catch(ExceptionA) {
   ProcessErrorA();
} catch(ExceptionB) {
   ProcessErrorB();
}
```

Now I think that copy pasting this code is a code smell.
One possible way to fix it to create a method that takes an action as argument, and does the try/catch. But it forces me to duplicate each method that is calling the try/catch, which leads to more code, less readable somehow.

What is the clean way to handle this problem, given that I cannot change the behavior of my external library ?

Comment: Are you going to execute the exact same code in response to the exact same exception, only it occured during different calls to that other library? I mean, does "ExceptionA" have the same response in *all* the cases?

Comment: A global exception handler might help maybe if it fits in your context, it the exception handling is about the same (like logging etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a common exception handler function

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                CallOtherLibrary();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HandleException(ex);
            }
        }


        private static void HandleException(Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is ExceptionA)
            {
                ProcessErrorA();
            }
            else if (ex is ExceptionB)
            {
                ProcessErrorB();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a `Dictionary<Type, Action> exceptionHandlers` and then call 
`exceptionHandlers[exception.GetType()]()` in the catch block.

```
    void ProcessErrorA() { }

    void Main() 
    {
        Dictionary<Type, Action> exceptionHandlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action>();
        exceptionHandlers.Add(typeof(NullReferenceException), ProcessErrorA);

        try{}
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            if (exceptionHandlers.ContainsKey(e.GetType()))
            {
                exceptionHandlers[e.GetType()]();
            }
            else 
            {
                // We don't have any handler for this exception. 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a wrapper of the alien library. In C# this is commonly done by using an `interface` with a method acting as an [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)/[Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

You create a new class acting as an adaptee, implementing the adapter interface and in the implemented method you will have the code you mentioned in the question. You then replace the original code with call to the method of your newly created adapter and use that one in your codebase instead.

The good thing about having an adapter for a library you don't own and using this adapter is not have to rewrite your own logic should the method signature of said external library change in the future, but merely change it in the adapting layer and you're all set again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this (adapt for own use):

```
class Program
{
    public int Divide_InExternalLib(int a, int b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("a={0}, b={1}", a, b));
        int result = a / b;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Result = {0}", result));
        return result;
    }


    public void CallExternalFunction(Action funct)
    {
        try
        {
            funct.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception caught: {0}", ex.ToString()));
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        int a = 6;
        int b = 2;
        p.CallExternalFunction(() => { p.Divide_InExternalLib(a, b); });
        b = 0;
        p.CallExternalFunction(() => { p.Divide_InExternalLib(a, b); });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output

```
a=6, b=2
Result = 3
a=6, b=0
Exception caught: System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
   at GenericExceptionHandling.Program.Divide_InExternalLib(Int32 a, Int32 b) in
 c:\users\siebiers\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\GenericExceptionHandlin
g\GenericExceptionHandling\Program.cs:line 16
   at GenericExceptionHandling.Program.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Main>b__1() in c:\u
sers\siebiers\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\GenericExceptionHandling\Gen
ericExceptionHandling\Program.cs:line 41
   at GenericExceptionHandling.Program.CallExternalFunction(Action funct) in c:\
users\siebiers\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\GenericExceptionHandling\Ge
nericExceptionHandling\Program.cs:line 26
```